# PHP for loop adding values to database

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have created and validated a for loop for an image upload. I am now trying to add these values to the database with other values that have previously been stored in a session in earlier parts of the site.

FOR Loop

```
for($i=1; $i<=$items; $i++) {
     $file_size = $_FILES["photo{$i}"]['size'];
     $file_name = $_FILES["photo{$i}"]['name'];
     $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
     $file_temp = $_FILES["photo{$i}"]['tmp_name']; 
     $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

     if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === false) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">[Photo '.$i.'] Format <strong>NOT</strong> acceptable. ';
        echo 'Accepted formats: '. implode(', ', $allowed).'</div>';
     } elseif($file_size > 1048576) {
        echo '<div class="alert-danger">[Photo '.$i.'] Image is too big. Maximium file size is 1MB.</div>';
     } else {
        // add values to database
     }
}
```

This is how I intended to insert all of the values into the database

```
$temp_data = array(
          'name'            => ucwords($_SESSION['name']),
          'email'           => strtolower($_SESSION['email']),
          'delivery'        => strtolower($_SESSION['delivery']),
          'item'            => sanitize($_GET['item']),
          'price'           => sanitize(($_GET['item'])*4.99), 
          'time_now'        => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
          'time_end'        => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+15 day")),
          'photo1'          => $file_path
        );

insert_temp($temp_data);
```

This is the code for `insert_temp` function.

```
function insert_temp($temp_data) {
array_walk($temp_data, 'array_sanitize');

$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($temp_data)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $temp_data) . '\'';
mysql_query("INSERT into `temp` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
```

}

---

This is the problem. I would like to insert the values which have been previously stored as sessions but also store the images in the for loop in the database. How can I do this without inserting the same values into the database over and over using the for loop?

Many thanks in advance, Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, user is "ordering" a line item consisting of a number ("item") and a price and a photo along with his email and name. What is the identifier of such a line item? If it is users email, set up a primary key on that and do an update instead of an insert if it exists.

Make yourself familiar with "[insert ... on duplicate key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-on-duplicate.html)"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you'll have to change up your schema.

Make a separate table for the photos and use a primary key to reference the reset of the data (put the id in the session data)

Also, I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that mysql_ is deprecated and you really should be using prepared statements.